# I want to change color in a Style tag HTML5, syntax is correct but it doesn't work, text is gray

Tags: html, html5-canvas, visual-web-developer

So basicly what is happening is that:
I have and H3 tag, inside I have a Style tag, which contain multiple properties:
[The H3 tag is the one im having problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX6oC.png)

As for syntax, its ok, but it still doesnt cahnge the color of the h3.
Please help!

Comment: add !important after color like color: black !important its will work for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think other classes from your css applied , so what you need to do is either you need to remove that class or Simply Write

```
<h3 style="color: black !important;">Any text</h3>
```

but `!important` is highly not recommended . for better practice make it class base.

Comment: I am actually trying to work on class base code, but this did made a change on my work, thanks you so much,  just posted another question, so if you are willing to, it would be much aprecciate if you can help me with that

Comment: any time brother you can mail me also when you stuck

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the particular Tag (i.e. h3), you should be able to see that the current property of color which you are applying is getting overridden.

To overcome this issue, you can do two things:

1. Improve the [Code Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
2. use `!important` next to the property as follows:

   ```
    <h3 style="color: black !important"> Header 3 </h3>
   ```

Note: It is never recommended to use `!important`

> Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.
>
> - [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)